# What's the time complexity for some python list operations?

Tags: python, list, time-complexity

I know it is some kind of basic question but I am not good at the fundamental things. I only know that for stack pop() method pops out the last element with O(1) time.

In python, it's allowed to pop any position in a list as well as to insert an element to any position, i.e. `list.pop(index)` and `list.insert(index, item)`. If the length of a list is `n`, what's the average time complexity of them?

Besides, is there a difference between `list.insert(index, item)` and `list = list[:index] + [item] + list[index:]`?

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: It's O(n); the expected number of items to move is still approximately n/2: (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n)/n.

Answer (score 0):

While `list.insert(index, item)` does practically the same thing as `list = list[:index] + [item] + list[index:]`, the python built-in function `list.insert` was made as a faster way to insert an item into a list. `list.insert` is more advanced and **is not equivalent to** `list = list[:index] + [item] + list[index:]` becuase it uses a different algorithim and is much faster.

The time complexity is O(n), which is approximately n/2.